# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka with confluent schema registry failed to send Message to channel output

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I would like to test Spring Cloud Stream with Confluent Schema Registry and Avro Schema evolution to integrate it with my application. I have found out that Spring Cloud Stream does not support a secure connection to Confluent Schema Registry and the implementation is still very basic. Hence, I have decided to use Confluent Schema Registry Client in conjunction with Spring Kafka for the schema registry part and use Spring Cloud Stream for the rest. Here is the code for Consumer and Producer as well as the Avro Schema:

Consumer:

```
import com.example.Sensor;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class ConsumerApplication {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void process(Sensor data) {
        logger.info(data);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class ConfluentSchemaRegistryConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient(@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}") String endpoint){
            CachedSchemaRegistryClient client = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(endpoint, 100);
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

Application.yaml:

```
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url: kafka-url:kafka-port
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: sensor-topic
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: https://user:password@schema-registry-url:schema-registry-port
      schema:
        avro:
          schema-locations: classpath:avro/sensor.avsc
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: SSL://kafka-url:kafka-port
          configuration:
            security.protocol: SSL
            ssl.truststore.type: JKS
            ssl.truststore.location: client.truststore.jks
            ssl.truststore.password: secret
            ssl.keystore.type: PKCS12
            ssl.keystore.location: client.keystore.p12
            ssl.keystore.password: secret
            ssl.key.password: secret
            key.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
            basic.auth.user.info: user:password
server.port: 9999
```

Producer:

```
import com.example.Sensor;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@RestController
public class Producer1Application {

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    private Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Producer1Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/messages", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendMessage() {
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(randomSensor()).build());
        return "ok, have fun with v1 payload!";
    }

    private Sensor randomSensor() {
        Sensor sensor = new Sensor();
        sensor.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-v1");
        sensor.setAcceleration(random.nextFloat() * 10);
        sensor.setVelocity(random.nextFloat() * 100);
        sensor.setTemperature(random.nextFloat() * 50);
        return sensor;
    }

    //Another convenience POST method for testing deterministic values
    @RequestMapping(value = "/messagesX", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendMessageX(@RequestParam(value="id") String id, @RequestParam(value="acceleration") float acceleration,
                               @RequestParam(value="velocity") float velocity, @RequestParam(value="temperature") float temperature) {
        Sensor sensor = new Sensor();
        sensor.setId(id + "-v1");
        sensor.setAcceleration(acceleration);
        sensor.setVelocity(velocity);
        sensor.setTemperature(temperature);
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(sensor).build());
        return "ok, have fun with v1 payload!";
    }

    @Configuration
    static class ConfluentSchemaRegistryConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient(@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}") String endpoint){
            CachedSchemaRegistryClient client = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(endpoint, 100);
            return client;
        }
    }

}
```

Application.yaml

```
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url: kafka-url:kafka-port
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: sensor-topic
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: https://user:password@schema-registry-url:schema-registry-port
      schema:
        avro:
          schema-locations: classpath:avro/sensor.avsc
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: SSL://kafka-url:kafka-port
          configuration:
            security.protocol: SSL
            ssl.truststore.type: JKS
            ssl.truststore.location: client.truststore.jks
            ssl.truststore.password: secret
            ssl.keystore.type: PKCS12
            ssl.keystore.location: client.keystore.p12
            ssl.keystore.password: secret
            ssl.key.password: secret
            key.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
            basic.auth.user.info: user:password
server.port: 9009
```

Consumer Schema:

```
{
  "namespace" : "com.example",
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Sensor",
  "fields" : [
    {"name":"id","type":"string"},
    {"name":"internalTemperature", "type":"float", "default":0.0, "aliases":["temperature"]},
    {"name":"externalTemperature", "type":"float", "default":0.0},
    {"name":"acceleration", "type":"float","default":0.0},
    {"name":"velocity","type":"float","default":0.0}
  ]
}
```

Producer Schema:

```
{
  "namespace" : "com.example",
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Sensor",
  "fields" : [
    {"name":"id","type":"string"},
    {"name":"temperature", "type":"float", "default":0.0},
    {"name":"acceleration", "type":"float","default":0.0},
    {"name":"velocity","type":"float","default":0.0}
  ]
}
```

I have stuck with the following exception. I would appreciate it if you could help me to understand what the issue is.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to convert message: 'GenericMessage [payload={"id": "a50a7646-a1c9-49a2-a7f6-f09b77fc3116-v1", "temperature": 10.430967, "acceleration": 5.434994, "velocity": 70.19337}, headers={id=de6e40e4-ba8f-9dca-1753-c06a1751e2d4, contentType=application/*+avro, timestamp=1556160207806}]' to outbound message.
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$OutboundContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.doPreSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:325) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$AbstractContentTypeInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:353) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:608) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:443) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at sample.producer1.Producer1Application.sendMessage(Producer1Application.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

P.S: I am using Confluent Client 5.2.1, Avro 1.8.2, Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Stream Fishtown.RELEASE.

Comment: any more stacktrace available? It doesn't look like the errors are related to any security configuration. I would like to see if there are more errors in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using Spring Cloud Stream release version 2.0+. If that's true, you might be facing an issue with content-type negotiation.
In the error message, the content-type header in the `GenericMessage` is `application/*+avro`. The default content-type since 2.0 is `application/json`.

You need to add a `org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter` to handle Avro content, which is missing from the configuration.
Refer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-preface-content-type-negotiation-improvements

-- Update --

The converter is already there just needs to be enabled explicitly for outbound messages, can be done via the configuration:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/*+avro
```

Consumer code looks fine, with the `SchemaRegistryClient`.

Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_avro_schema_registry_client_message_converters

Comment: So there is no Message Converter for Avro and I need to implement a custom one?

Comment: Okay, I think there's no need for an explicit converter if I look into the docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#_avro_schema_registry_client_message_converters.  For incoming messages, your code looks fine as you have defined a `SchemaRegistryClient`.  But for outbound messages, you need a configuration to enable the avro converter `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/*+avro`.  Do you have this in your application?

Comment: Yes. It is already covered in the application yaml file for the producer.

Comment: do have a demo project (on github maybe) that I could view and debug locally?

Comment: I have actually created this from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/schema-registry-samples/schema-registry-confluent